# How to keep temporary files between multiple runs in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, temporary-files

I have a small node module which generates files.

As it is really slow and will produce the same result for the same input I would like to keep the last compilation together with a control hash.

The question is now where do I have to place the temporary files so it can be easily accessed?

The cache should also work if the main node application which depends on my module restarts.

Comment: You can put them anywhere in the file system that you have read/write access to and where the general public does not have access to.  Where that is depends upon your OS, your deployment/hosting environment, how you have permissions set up, where your app is deployed in the file system and what permissions your app is running under - none of which you have disclosed in your question.

Comment: I know that node can place files anywhere - but where is the intended location for npm modules?

Comment: As I said in my comment, that depends upon a whole lot of things which you do not disclose.  There is no "npm standard" for where to put module specific temporary files that applies across all operating systems and all deployment scenarios.  Personally, I would centralize all temp files for an app in some sort of single `cache` sub-directory rather than let each module do its own.  But, that's just one person's opinion.  There is no standard I'm aware of.

Comment: I am not talking about an app but about a npm module which might be used by an app ;)

Comment: Like I said, there is no convention for where a module puts temp files that I am aware of.  If I were using a module, I would NOT want it to decide that on it's own as it can completely vary by deployment scenario.  I would want that to be a configuration option for the module so the app could tell it where to put temp files.  If you want a default, use the OS default for temp files or create a sub-directory called "temp" below the module's directory and use that.  But that might not be ideal for some deployment scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for your advices - I hoped there would be a best practice. It would be configurable but should have a good default. I guess  I will go with a local temp directory inside the modules directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll collect all my comments into an answer.

As far as I know, there is no NPM standard for where a module would put it's tempfiles.  The best place to put them can depend upon how file permissions are configured, what operating system you're running, what permissions the host app is running under, the type of hosting environment, etc...

The logical options are as follows:

1. In the OS temp directory
2. In a `temp` sub-directory below the module directory.
3. In a configurable directory that the user of the module can specify either via a config argument or via an environment variable.

You can find out where the OS temp directory is with [`os.tmpdir()`](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_tmpdir).

A `temp` sub-directory below the module.  Keep in mind that there can be multiple processes using a module so if you're putting files in a location that may be shared by multiple processes, then you need to be using generated unique names if the files are supposed to be separate per process or appropriate locking if the files are supposed to be shared among processes.

And, don't forget about cleanup maintenance so there's no build-up of temporary files over time.